# iPhone - creating a triggered method

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating my custom control from scratch. Like a UIScrollView I have to have a delegate method that triggers when the control starts sliding, something like scrollViewDidScroll.

I thought of putting a call inside touchesMoved checking for every move change, but I did something like for testing and it is very expensive and makes touchesMoved slow.

A second approach would be creating a NSTimer triggering a method every x milliseconds to see if the control is on another position and then trigger the method, but I am not sure about that, because if will be constantly checking the control, consuming CPU even if the control is not moving.

What is the best way to do that? How do you guys would do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the timer approach is right, i would suggest that you start the timer at touch start and stop it at touch ended or 3-4 seconds after touch ended if you would calculate the bouncing and deceleration

Comment: I actually used it in one of my projects and it worked quite well, i too had bad performance with using your same solution

Answer (score 0):

I really think you shouldn't re-invent the wheel and write a custom control from scratch. Subclass UIControl. It has 3methods

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

in which you can perform your checks and fire you actions.

Comment: in this case I have, because I am working on Cocos2D, subclassing one of its classes of layers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIGestureControl in place of touchesMoved: , create your delegate methods and pass to the delegate your didScroll: method

Comment: gestures are even slower than touches, so it would be a bad decision :)